# Splitting and converting a large tif files into multiple .hgt files

Tags: gdal, convert, geotiff-tiff, hgt

I'm quite new to GIS format and conversions, so be patient with a newbie. I got stuck on a file conversion and I'm looking for some help this to fix my scripts. I have a big **5 GB tif** file with a precision of 5 meters and these features:

Dimensions X: 27176 Y:.49586 Band: 1
Origin 555121,4.4447e+06
Pixel dimension 5,-5
No value:-9999 
AREA_OR_POINT=Area
STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=2237.2060546875
STATISTICS_MEAN=520.43425935058
STATISTICS_MINIMUM=-2.8499999046326
STATISTICS_STDDEV=429.22835999081
Data type: Float32
+proj=utm +zone=33 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
Layer extension (original layer projection)
555120.6040000000502914,4196769.7539999997243285 : 691000.6040000000502914,4444699.7539999997243285

I'm getting that each hgt file covers 1 degree lat and 1 degree lon, and has to have a size of 1201x1201.

My intent is to convert this single tif into one or more hgt files. I suppose that given the tif dimensions (X: 27176 Y:.49586) I have first to split into multiple tif files and then convert into multiple hgt file. To do this I'm using GDAL scripts from QGIS:

[image]

If I try a direct conversion to hgt I get this warning and error:

*Warning 1: The corner coordinates of the source are not properly aligned on plain latitude/longitude boundaries. 
ERROR 1: Image dimensions should be 1201x1201, 3601x3601 or 1801x3601.*

So I defined these scripts below:

Step 1:

```
gdalwarp -of GTiff -srcnodata 32767 -t_srs "+proj=utm +zone=33 +datum=WGS84" -rcs -order 3 -ts 1201 1201 -multi C:/Users/C012426/Desktop/geocoding/5m_33N/DEM_5m_33N.tif C:/Users/C012426/Desktop/geocoding/5m_33N/DEM_5m_33N_warped.tif
```

Step 2:

```
gdal_translate -of SRTMHGT C:/Users/C012426/Desktop/geocoding/5m_33N/DEM_5m_33N_warped.tif C:/Users/C012426/Desktop/geocoding/5m_33N/DEM_5m_33N_warped.hgt
```

What I get instead is one file only named: N4196770E55.hgt

while I was expecting to get 27176 / 2101 = about 22 hgt files...

What is wrong in my theory and most of all in my scripts ?

Comment: You must also define the extents of each tile to match with the definition https://dds.cr.usgs.gov/srtm/version2_1/Documentation/Quickstart.pdf

Comment: Thanks @user30184, as I'm in SRTM3 zone of the world, it should be 1201x1201, but I can set these in the scripts ?

Comment: It is not only to set output into 1201x1201 but you must set also the input, the region you want to store into each file. With gdal_translate that is set with -projwin. And then the same thing again for all your about 22 regions.

Comment: Thanks again @user30184, unfortunately I can write just java code, while GDAL APIs seem to be for other languages. Last question: are you aware of any tool able to do the splitting of the tif into smaller tif files ?

Comment: GDAL has java bindings. I know tile cutting tools but not any that knows out-of-the box how to cut hgt tiles.

Comment: Thanks, ok  I will look both for the bindings and the tiff tile cutting tools, if i can get tiles from the big file than trasforming into single hgt is not the real problem, getting the small tiff files is the one so for me :).

Comment: I guess it won't help you since you're using java, but I had a similar problem with splitting tiffs and posted my Python solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41742162/gdal-readasarray-for-vrt-extremely-slow/45745848#45745848. You would manually set dx and dy to 1201 or whatever dimensions you want in the first line of the script (instead of using the optimal_tile_size function).  After you have your tile coordinates, you can easily loop through them and export to HGT with gdal. See this page for info @ the HGT driver: http://www.gdal.org/frmt_various.html#SRTMHGT

Answer (score 1):

After some researches I found that I can do tif splitting via ArcGIS, py console:

[image]

Then i will have to translate all tif files to HGT but this look like an half of the problem.

Script is:

import arcpy
arcpy.SplitRaster_management("C:/Users/Desktop/geocoding/DEM_Calabria_5m_33N/DEM_Calabria_5m_33N.tif", "C:/Users/Desktop/geocoding/EM_Calabria_5m_33N/",
                             "ras", "SIZE_OF_TILE", "TIFF", "NEAREST",
                             "#", "1201 1201", "10", "PIXELS", "#","#","#", "#","#","-32767")